# IDA plugin to view hex bytes similar to objdump

Tags: ida, objdump

Is there a plugin or option in IDA that interleavs the hex bytes for 
each instruction similar to the output of `objdump`? I.e. like this:

```
   1800035f1:   ff 15 19 5a 00 00       callq  *0x5a19(%rip)        # 0x180009010                          
   1800035f7:   45 8b c6                mov    %r14d,%r8d                                                  
   1800035fa:   48 8d 55 d7             lea    -0x29(%rbp),%rdx                                            
   1800035fe:   48 8d 4b 10             lea    0x10(%rbx),%rcx                                             
   180003602:   ff 15 b0 1c 00 00       callq  *0x1cb0(%rip)        # 0x1800052b8                          
   180003608:   48 8d 7d ef             lea    -0x11(%rbp),%rdi                                            
   18000360c:   41 8d 4e ff             lea    -0x1(%r14),%ecx                                             
   180003610:   49 3b c6                cmp    %r14,%rax                                                   
   180003613:   74 12                   je     0x180003627                                                 
   180003615:   33 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
```

I dont want to switch to hex view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need for plugins. Just enter a non-zero value in "Number of opcode bytes"  in Options-General-... Disassembly.